# How To Display Node Tokens/Keys/Content Fields In Twig Template

Tags: theming

I'm fairly new to theming with Drupal, especially using Templates and Twig. After a lot of searching and experimenting I seem that have accomplished my desired view mode the way I want...almost.

I have a field in my content type called Category. The machine name is field_category. I have been able to output the field in my template using the key: {{content.field_category}} But as you can see it also applies a CSS styling I have on the full default Node Page which I would prefer not to have it there.

[image: Twig Template Category Field Output]

Going at it a different way, I used a View along with the given replacement patterns and was given the token of {{ field_category }}. After everything was done it does the same thing without any CSS styling since it's not pulling in the HTML markup of class="field field--name-field-category".

[image: Views Category Field Output]

My question is I wonder if there is a way to grab the value without the markup? And if so how? Any steps in the right direction would be very much appreciated, I am a complete beginner at Drupal and even more so with Twig. Thank you.

Comment: `{{ content.field_category[0] }}` will likely do the trick

Comment: That absolutely did do the trick, thank you for your help! I kept on getting issues when using Kint or Dump and wasn't able to fix this by myself but your answer did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Drupal 8 you now have two ways to access to the data of a given node/entity.

The first is with the `{{ content.* }}` this will return the content that went through the display plugins/system (everything which you configure in the "Display mode" of the content type).

You also can access to the raw data with `{{ node.*.value }}`

It's preferably that you use the way `{{ content.* }}` as much as possible in order to be able to use the power of Drupal to quickly change the things with display mode.